# How to change the color of UITableViewCell selected view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How to change the gray color when cell been selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Kjuly and @Selkie's answer. I make it works with both of you.

1. set `selectedBackgroundView`'s backgroundColor first.
2. change `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor` and `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` at `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath`.

Thank you again.

Comment: In my opinion, option 2 is not very good workaround though it works. As it will always change cell's normal backgroundColor when it is selected, and when it is deselected, it need to be set to normal again!

Answer (score 3):

When user click on Selected Row

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `selectedBackgroundView`'s color as what you want in your custom tableview cell (which is a subclass of UITableViewCell):

```
UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
[selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // set color here
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
[selectedBackgroundView release];
```

or you can configure it in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
//...
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about change the background color in delegate method:

```
-（void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```