# How to make a table in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a table on iOS that it can highlight the cell on which user taps (what the Excel does).

Is it almost possible with Objective-C? 
In which direction should I go to create such thing (use UIKit for example)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572458/how-to-change-the-color-of-uitableviewcell-selected-view

Comment: If you need a table with only one column but multiple rows -> UITableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely certain if it's possible to build an excel style table, I would assume that it is since you can customize tables a lot. Apple has lots of great documentation about how to build tables and customize them accordingly. If it can be done, you'll find out how to do it from one of these links:

Documentation on `UITableViewController`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Documentation on `UITableView`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Documentation on `UITableViewCell`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think user3237855 needs a spreadsheet like excel provides which is not so easy =( if so have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892174/ms-excel-type-spreadsheet-creation-using-objective-c-for-ios-app

Comment: Ahh, I see, I think your right.  I don't know how to do that off the top of my head but I'm sure that if it's possible, the way to do it can be found in one of the links I gave him/her

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 2-dimensional table then you want a UICollectionView, not a table view. UITableviews are strictly one-dimensional, with optional grouping into sections.

Collection views can be anything you want, including 2-dimensional tables. You might want to do some googling to see if somebody has already created a spreadsheet control using collection views.